# Port forwarding not working for certain LAN IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, lan

I hope someone can shed some light on this.  My knowledge of networking is basic at best.

I have a CentOS server on two networks:

- NIC1 is on a public IP with gateway set sitting on Switch 1. (ADSL Internet)
- NIC2 is set to 10.10.10.2 with no gateway set sitting on Switch 2. (Cable Internet)
- Switch 2's gateway/router is 10.10.10.1. (ASUS router)

Within the LAN, other LAN pc's are able to access 10.10.10.2 on open ports.  When a port forward rule is set from gateway/router 10.10.10.1 --> 10.10.10.2, this isn't working.  Port forwarding on gateway/router 10.10.10.1 --> to 10.10.10.3 works (Windows machine with gateway set to 10.10.10.1).

Is it possible to reach 10.10.10.2 from the public internet through the ASUS router 10.10.10.1?

Answer (score 1):

IP policy routing.

I found two write-ups of the same that I used to update my CentOS server to enable the 2nd NIC to receive and send packets.  Also was successful in updating another similar server with a dual NICs/gateways.

http://jensd.be/468/linux/two-network-cards-rp_filter <-- I went with setting up IP policies under the 'best solution' section and did not change the rp_filter value.  This write-up also has nice diagrams.

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/ensure_symmetric_routing_on_a_server_with_multiple_default_gateways.html  <--additional example of the above which made it clearer for me.

If you want the changes permanent, then follow the instructions on the first link above.

### My example:

- ip route add 99.88.77.66/24 dev eth0 table 1 (example Public IP #1)
- ip route add default via 99.88.77.1 table 1 (example Public IP #1's gateway)
- ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 dev eth1 table 2 (second NIC on different network)
- ip route add default via 10.10.10.1 table 2 (ASUS router gateway)
- ip rule add from 99.88.77.66/32 table 1 priority 100
- ip rule add from 10.10.10.4/32 table 2 priority 110
- ip route flush cache

The /24 for you may change depending on subnet mask of your IP's.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to understand why your setup doesn't work. To do this we need to consider what happens.

- A connection attempt comes in from the "cable" internet connection.
- The NAT router modifies the destination address and sets up a mapping table entry.
- The packet reaches your server, and a response is generated.
- Your server looks up the destination for the response in it's routing table and sends the packet to the default gateway (e.g. towards the "ADSL" internet connection).
- Most likely the packet gets dropped for having a bogus source address. Even if it does make it back to the client it's source address won't match the one the client expects so the client will drop it as bogus.

Now we understand what is going wrong we can do something about it. There are a few options.

Option 1 is to use "policy routing" on the server to route the traffic based on source IP. This is the best option of the server supports it (recent versions of linux do). [Stile's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1129394/506601) covers how to set up policy routing on a Linux server to route based on source address.

Option 2 is to point the default gateway of the server at a box that can do policy routing. Then that box can route the traffic correctly depending on it's source IP. This may be a useful soloution if the server OS doesn't support policy routing.

Option 3 is to make the NAT box Masqurade for the traffic that it is port forwarding. I would consider this a last-resort option as it hides the real source address of the traffic.